# ArrayAdapter's Textview takes all the screen

Tags: android, android-layout

The Textview used by ArrayAdapter is taking the whole screen and the "title" and "description" Textviews are not shown...I'd like to show them before the list, help?

Here is my code:

```
TextView titleText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.title);
titleText.setText(sitesList.getTitle());

TextView descriptionText = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.description);
descriptionText.setText(sitesList.getDescription());

ArrayList<String> Categories = sitesList.getCategory();
ListView lv = new ListView(this);
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.main,R.id.list_item,Categories));
setContentView(lv);
```

My layout file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting this because you set your `ListView` in your `setContentView`.Instead,add it to your `LinearLayout` and then your `ListView` would appear along with both two `TextView`s you specified for title and description.

One more thing,i think,you should either use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` in adapter or you need to create custom `xml` for your customized `TextView` and use that there,then adding

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

in your `xml`.

So basically your xml would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and your cusotmized xml would be:

**custom_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

So finally your adapter string would be:

```
lv.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.custom_item,R.id.list_item,Categories));
```

and then,

```
LinearLayout layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(lv);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

Comment: I get the same "Unable to start activity" error and the "Force close" window :(

Comment: put setContentView on the first line and you can later inflate the list or put the list in xml layout

Answer (score 0):

if you want "title" and "description" Textviews and than ListView

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical">
   <TextView android:id="@+id/title"
      ... />
   <TextView android:id="@+id/description"
      ... />
   <ListView android:id="@+id/list_item"
      ... />
</LinearLayout>
```

in java code:

```
setContentView(R.layouts.yourxml);

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(...)
lv.setAdapter(...)
```

if you want list item with 3 TextView use costume adapter